# Single MVC Web Application with multiple URLs redirecting to diferent Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, routes

To share the code of 2 landing pages (ex. footer, newsletter subscription) I need to be able to redirect `http://page1.company.com` to the `Index()` method of `Page1Controller` and `http://page2.company.com` to `Index()` method of `Page2Controller`.
How can I do this in a MVC C# Web Application with IIS7?

Is this a good practice or should I create 2 diferent Web Aplications? In this solution, how could I share a common view like a footer?